# Is it possible to create UIView with curved bottom edge.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I need to create UIView with curved bottom edge as follows. What would be the easiest way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just set your view in IB to ShapedView class, or create it from code and play with control point when drawing path.

```
class ShapedView: UIView {
    let subLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let subLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        subLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return subLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(subLayer)
        subLayer.frame = bounds
        setPath()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        subLayer.frame = bounds
        setPath()
    }

    private func setPath() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:bounds.height))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:bounds.width, y:bounds.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y:4*bounds.height/5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:bounds.width, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        subLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `CAShapeLayer`

Do following

1) Create `CAShapeLayer`

2) Create `UIBezierPath`

3) Assign `path`  to `CAShapeLayer`

4) Add that `CAShapeLayer` to `mask` of `UIVIew`

Hope it is helpful to you